# Printing the dictionary value out in Django template

Tags: django

I am passing a two dictionaries called `student_ids` and `rows` to a Django template. The dictionary `student_ids` has a key called `student_id` and `invite_id` and I would like to print out the `student_ids[student_id]` to get the `invite_id`.

The 4th element in row in rows dictionary is the same as `student_id`. When I try the code below, it doesn’t work…

Django template:

```
{% for row in rows %}
    <a href="#invite"
     data-invite="{{ invite_ids.row.4 }}">
     {{ row.2 }}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

What should I do to get the correct data out in the Django template? I essentially need `student.ids[row[4]]` to be printed out, and for it to be simple…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it this way:

```
{% for t_id, i_id in teacher_invite_ids.items %}
 {% if t_id == row.4 %}
  {{ i_id }}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 7):

> The dictionary `student_ids` has a key called `student_id` and `invite_id` and I would like to print out the `student_ids[student_id]` to get the `invite_id`.

Try this:

```
{% for sid, iid in student.ids.items %}
    {{ sid }} -- {{ iid }}
{% endfor %}
```

Btw: your dictionary name is wierd and confusing because of that dot. I would change it to `studentIds` or something ...

---

Updated based on your edits:

First check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for

I really dont understand exactly what you are after but if you want to access a value from the rows dict based on a key which is equal to a `student_id` you can try this and see how it works out for you and adjust it to your needs:

```
{% for student_id, student_id_value in student.ids.items %}
     {{ student_id }}
     {{ rows.student_id }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i need the student.ids[row[4]] to be printed out... How do i that?

Comment: bascially i want the value called invite_id. it is a value with u get when u type student.ids[row[4]].. i do not want to loop through the whole list.. just one key at each time and key is row[4].

Comment: for i am looking for is nested dictionaries